# AJAX freezes webpage, throwing warning that slowing down browser

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am utilizing an AJAX call to make a request to the Alpha Vantage API and return JSON with data on stock symbols/tickers when searching on each key press:

```js
function edValueKeyPress() {
     var keywords = document.getElementById("TextBox89").value;
     if (keywords.length >= 2) {
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=" + keywords + "&apikey=B8ARVH4ULKOPMDOT",
            "method": "GET"
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
             var keywordsArray = [];
             var json = response["bestMatches"];
             for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                 keywordsArray.push(json[i]["1. symbol"] + " - " + json[i]["2. name"]);
             }
             $("#TextBox89").autocomplete({
                  source: keywordsArray
             });
        });
     }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
Enter stock symbol/ticker: <input id="TextBox89" onKeyPress="edValueKeyPress()" onKeyUp="edValueKeyPress()">
```

As you can clearly see in my code snippet, the stock symbols and company names are pulled from the `jqueryui autocomplete()` method and it works. It also works in this CodePen: https://codepen.io/max-voisard/pen/jOPERRd.

However, when running on my website on this [webpage](https://maxstechandmathsite.azurewebsites.net/Random/News.aspx), it causes the page to go unresponsive and freeze in all browsers, and only sometimes will the `autocomplete()` respond and work. I'm thinking there must be another script on my page causing the timeout, but the page only freezes when typing input into the textbox/search box. So I'm thinking there's something wrong with the AJAX; either it is not running its asynchronous nature properly or it is clogging the pipes of the webpage with too much data on the API call.

Also, I know I shouldn't put my API key in client-side code like JavaScript and instead in server-side code, but it is difficult to implement an `autocomplete()` method that way. It also isn't a sensitive API key.

Comment: [Seems to work for me.](https://imgur.com/a/xpxBsnI)

Comment: @OliverNi You mean on my webpage?

Comment: Yeah, the autocomplete is slow, but I couldn't get it to freeze up

Comment: @OliverNi Okay, my network must be slower. Is there a way I can wait for a response and prevent the freeze?

Answer (score 0):

Since this was a request on bulk quantities of data, the AJAX needed enough time in its timeout set from the browser to retrieve the data. Simply adding `"timeout": 1000000` to the AJAX call did the trick for me. Get this: there is no timeout set for an AJAX call by default! So really, you should **always** be setting timeouts for AJAX calls - especially for bulk data requests - and this problem was considerably avoidable. Also, make sure the `cache` is set to `false`, so not too much memory is allocated.

```
$.ajax({
    "timeout": 1000000,
    "cache": false
});
```